# Train grown outdoor cat using the litter box

Tags: cats, training, toilet-training, house-moving

I have a grown outdoor cat. We will move in a few months and then we want the cat to stay in the house for the first days in the new home.

So in those days my cat has to use the litter box. How to train a grown outdoor cat to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats by birth have clean litter habits. They always search for something like soil with which they can cover their excreta.

When outdoor cat is put indoor and she finds only litter box and no soil type substance in any other place, the cat will automatically do their private business in litter box.

They don't require litter box training.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cat in a small room such as a bathroom, with only the litter box, food, and water. Do not give the. A bed, towel, or any other soft surface. Soft things like bedding tend to be inviting to pee on. After a few days the litter box will smell like kitty and they will be more likely to use the litter box instead of your laundry or other soft substrate.